# What are possible methods to beat a goblin clone attack?

Tags: clash-royale

In Clash Royale's 2v2 games there is an attack move which I have not been able to beat during any game. Both players send two goblin barrels each(using the mirror card) to the King Tower and then both will use a clone to increase the number.

As there are 3 goblins in each barrel this means that each player sends 6 goblins over. If the 12 goblins are cloned twice this results in 36 goblins around the King Tower.

What ways are there of beating such an attack as I have lost every game when this has happened in less than 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of cards to counter this move, like Arrow, Poison, Valkyrie, Electro Wizard, even Mega Knight.

However, I think it is best to "read" their moves and spending elixir efficiently. Goblin Barrel takes time between being thrown until it lands. If the direction is to your King Tower, then be ready to counter it. And it is expensive to launch Goblin Barrel + Mirror + Clone, so they must have been holding cards for a while. If you play it right, you shouldn't die in their first move.

Answer (score 0):

I use a hog cycle deck with log, fire spirits, ice spirits, and mega knight. All 4 are great counters and it is unlikely that you won't have at least one of these cards.

Answer (score 0):

As the diameter of the goblins' circle would most likely be too large for a log or fire spirits, and freeze spells would also be too small, try arrows. They has a large radius of 4 and only costs 3 elixir.